# Removing text shadow/blur from chart.js charts

Tags: chart.js

There is a mild shadow/blur effect on the text in the chart. I haven't figured out how to remove that. Does anyone know how to do so? I'm using version 2.7.1. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps attach a screen shot?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated my question to add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do the same cross-browser?
Are you able to change the font? Perhaps its not a good screen display font.

Are you using a mac?
Take a look at [font-smoothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) on MDN. Note it is not standard.

Could be something to do with font aliasing.

```
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, it occurs cross-browser. I'm able to change the font. (The shadow/blur remains when I change the font.) The same font and size does not have the effect when loaded in plain HTML/CSS.